# Boost: Single Threaded IO Service

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-context

In my app I will receive various events that I would like to process asynchronously in a prioritised order.

I could do this with a `boost::asio::io_service`, but my application is single threaded. I don't want to pay for locks and `mallocs` you might need for a multi threaded program (the performance cost really is significant to me). I'm basically looking for a `boost::asio::io_service` that is written for single threaded execution.

I'm pretty sure I could implement this myself using `boost::coroutine`, but before I do, does something like a `boost::asio::io_service` that is written for single threaded execution exist already? I scanned the list of boost libraries already and nothing stood out to me

Comment: you can put io_service::run() int main();

Comment: Call `io_service::run()` from a [single thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html).

Comment: @IgorR. of course internally, the service object will still lock its queue. But, I smell premature optimization. Just implement it using an interface that allows you to replace the nuts&bolts if you really do find that "all the synchronization" is killing your throughput/sending latency through the roof.

Comment: Would be good to know that locking overhead will be visible only after more than a couple hundred thousands ops per sec. That's well above 99% apps out there. Probably it's better to just go ahead and add that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that you *have* to pay for synchronization as soon as you use any non-blocking calls of Asio.

Even though you might use a single thread for scheduling work and processing the resulting callbacks, Asio might still have to spawn additional threads internally for executing asynchronous calls. Those will access the `io_service` concurrently.

Think of an `async_read` on a socket: As soon as the received data becomes available, the socket has to notify the `io_service`. This happens concurrent to your main thread, so additional synchronization is required.

For blocking I/O this problem goes away in theory, but since asynchronous I/O is sort of the whole point of the library, I would not expect to find too many optimizations for this case in the implementation.

As was [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902911/boost-single-threaded-io-service#comment40547297_25902911) already, the contention on the `io_service` will be very low with only one main thread, so unless profiling indicates a clear performance bottleneck there, you should not worry about it too much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use boost::asio together with boost::coroutine -> boost::asio::yield_context (does already the coupling between coroutine + io_service). If you detect an task with higher priority you could suspend the current task and start processing the task with higher priority.
The problem is that you have to define/call certain check-points in the code of your task in order to suspend the task if the condition (higher prio task enqueued) is given.